# Swift shadow on tableview with dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem with dynamic content with shadow on table view

I had an extension for make corner radius and make shadow

```
extension UIView {

func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath

    self.layer.mask = mask

    let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shadowLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shadowLayer.frame = self.frame

    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 2
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.13
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 6
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)

    self.superview!.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, below: self.layer)
    }
}
```

And This id MyCustomTableViewCell

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    bg_view.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 9)
}
```

And This My result (text is "this is my data on table")

[image: My current re sult]

I also use

```
activity_table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
activity_table.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

And Set line to 0

Comment: Your problem is that you are accessing your bounds and frame properties from awakeFromNib. Ideally, you would do that in your tableView's cellForRow at method or in your cells layoutSubviews method. The bounds and frame properties are not fully initialized in awakeFromNib.

Comment: I have done that but same result. I try to print bg_view hight in cellForRow but it return same width as height of view in storyboard. Is it have some way to know actual hight of view after call the API. (the height that return is height of view before call API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this some more. You are making this way more complicated than it needs to be. I was able to solve this problem without the need for sublayers.

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 9
        containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.13
        containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
        containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    }
}
```

containerView is simply a subView that contains the label. Now, with the containerView, you would adjust the shadowing and the rounded corners.

You can check out the full solution [here](https://github.com/robertcrabtree/RoundedCorners).

The only thing you need to make sure of is that the containerView's background color is not clear. If so, you are going to see some funky side effects where shadows are propagated to the text label.